# propertygrid adding two models in a form

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I've a problem:
I've an item which is called: ServerStatus
This item i am adding with `this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = item;` to my propertygrid.
But I've 2 WCF Services and wanna add to this propertygrid (=> in that my item is) an other modelitem (can't use +=);

is there a way to do this ? or do i need to make a model for both modelitems ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks im sry about that

Comment: A propertygrid can't display 2 objects at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirement is but a PropertyGrid is capable of displaying common properties for several instances. If you modify a property, the value will be assigned to all selected target instances. If a property has different values for the target instances, a blank field will be displayed.

```
myGrid.SelectedObjects = new object[] { item1, item2 };
```